# How to enable replication history in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-replication

When one logs into a mysql slave and does a STOP SLAVE; the replication stops. I'm trying to see if the slave can be configured to log this.

I looked at the tables in performance_schema and the tables related to replication all seem to only have info about the current status. I'm looking for something that helps me identify when replication stopped and when it resumed, something like this:

```
Operation     |   <time>
STOP SLAVE    |   <timestamp>
START SLAVE   |   <timestamp>
```

I'm concerned only about when replication was stopped and when it was turned on again. I am not looking for anything else.

Enabling the general query log I think is one way to achieve this but it would log almost everything taking place which is wasteful. So is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: hi, perhaps enabling verbose logging / tracing will print a message when the state is changed?

Answer (score 1):

Found something in the error logs, mysql-error.log under /var/lib/mysql logs all the errors and also happens to log when replication starts and stops.